# Compact Proofs of Retrievability publicly verifiable with RSA

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, group-theory

I'm currently trying to implement compact proofs of retrievability that are publicly verifiable by RSA as described in this paper [Compact Proofs of Retrievability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/073.pdf) in GO. I'm currently struggling on page 26 with the following equation:

$$
σ_i \leftarrow \left(H(\text{name}\mathbin\|i) \cdot \Pi_{j=1}^s u_j^{m_{ij}}\right)^d \bmod N  
$$

Especially the exponentiation part is a problem, as $u_j$ and $m_{ij}$ are way to big to calculate. I have the following numbers, the prime modulus is N = 2048 bits, $m_{ij}$ is a sector of 2047 bits, $u_j$ is a random number of between $(0,N]$. So I think the restriction that those elements must be part of $\mathbb{Z_N}$ holds. Maybe someone can correct me there?
Is there some clever calculation I can do instead of just naively exponentiating $u_j$ with $m_{ij}$? I think all the operations are done in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z_N^*}$, but unfortunately I lack the knowledge to put it to clever use.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Use the [modular exponentiation function](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Exp) Exp(u,m,N)

Comment: That's what i did.  It looks like the following:
`new(big.Int).Exp(u[j], m[i][j], nil)` where both values u_j and m_ij have the properties i described above. I set N to nil, as i just want to exponentiate in the inner term of the function where u_j^m_ij.

Comment: Set $N$ to $N$, the mod operation should be applied to all of the individual operations.

Comment: @DanielS Thanks for your comment again. Okay, just to get you right. It would look like this:
$$
σ_i \leftarrow \left(H(\text{name}\mathbin\|i) \cdot \Pi_{j=1}^s u_j^{m_{ij}} \bmod N\right)^d \bmod N  
$$
where the mod operation is now also applied for every single operation. Is this correct? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, that is correct apply mod with every exponentiation and multiplication. The answer will be the same, but the computation will be much more efficient.

Comment: @DanielS Thank you very much! Pretty obvious after I checked up on modular arithmetic again.